# Google Cloud Endpoints discovery document changes / evolution support on iOS?

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm implementing the iOS client-side of our Google Cloud Endpoints API, and want to know how Cloud Endpoints discovery documents get interpreted internally on iOS, so when I make changes on the Cloud Endpoints side (add a field, change a field name, delete a field) what happens to older clients?

I know that Cloud Endpoints exposes a REST JSON API for the Javascript/AngularJS side of things which we could tie into manually using something like AFNetworking on iOS. I'm familiar with how to manage API changes on the client in that scenario, but if it makes sense to utilize the Toolkit SDK / RPC implementation, then I'd rather do that.

Is this all handled by versioning the API, then? So older clients would request an older version of the API? Does the Google iOS SDK support semantic versioning then? I could see version numbers getting out of control quickly if not.

Note this is the python version of GCE.

Answer (score 0):

You should be generating and using a client library, ultimately, if you don't want to both yourself with all kinds of implementation details of how to call the endpoints API. On the other hand, if you were to go with AFNetworking, it would be up to you do do your research as to how REST APIs can be called with AFNetworking. The REST API defined by endpoints can be read about [in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/), and in addition you can use the API Explorer to test your methods and even capture the headers sent with these requests in your browser.

Secondly, it goes without saying that you shouldn't code an API, then change its specs radically without versioning it or notifying/updating any clients. The version system is implemented A) in the client library generated from your discovery doc and B) in the URL route of the REST API itself. You would want to choose whichever naming scheme for versioning that your target framework supports.

I hope this has cleared up any confusion for you.

Comment: So it's basically the bog standard REST API stuff.. once you deploy with clients, there's no changing field names or anything unless you want to version the endpoint or version the entire API?

Comment: I mean, of course you *could* redeploy the same version of the API with changes made, but I was referring to best practices. It's best to keep a version of an API in development until it's passing tests and then deploy it once and for all as that version. Once you have deployed a version, unless it's a minor patch that won't break things or affect how the client should call the API, it's better to provision a new version for yourself to work, especially if making changes to aspects such as parameter lists, data types, the nature of the code inside a method and its side-effects, etc...